# Is there a Yelp-equivalent in Croatia?

Tags: online-resources, croatia, reviews

That is, where can I go to find crowd-sourced ratings of restaurants, clinics, etc?  I'm looking for something by and for Croatians, rather than tourists (in other words, not Tripadvisor).

Comment: Did you check Foursquare? Most of the comments are in croatian so my guess is that locals use it.

Comment: Tripadvisor isn't necessarily foreign tourists. Plenty (maybe most) TA restraunt reviews in the UK seem to be written by locals. No idea if that does apply to Croatia however.

Comment: @CMaster no, TripAdvisor isn't *entirely* foreign tourists, but one would expect it to have relatively more of those users because it is designed specifically as a platform for tourists to post reviews, while Yelp caters to both locals and tourists, so I think OP's question is reasonable. That said, it is certainly hard to quantify how tourist-heavy a review site is, and the tourist-local balances of various sites/apps probably vary by locale.

Comment: Can you read Croatian? Likely a review website by and for Croatians will not be in English.  And machine translations tend to lose the nuances that are a vital part of understanding the underlying emotion.

Comment: @Tom I can't read Croatian, but nor do I feel I need to understand the nuances of "underlying emotion".  I just need, for example, a dentist who does reasonably good work, as could be ascertained from a star rating.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Google Maps. There are plenty of reviews in English and Croatian.

Answer (score 1):

The international equivalent is [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/). Searching for "[dentists in Zagreb](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Zagreb%2C%20Croatia&nearGeoId=72057594041114822&q=Dentist%27s%20Office)" yields plenty of comments from local Croats:

[image]